# The organization of TCP/IP header files

Tags: c, linux, tcp

Someone can explain why the TCP/IP header files been organized like this.

In `libc6-dev` on ubuntu-14.04:

```
arpa/
netinet/
x86-64-linux-gnu/
...
```

Why?

Comment: Why not? Are you really hoping to get hold of a TCP/IP developer here, when the work was done thirty years ago?

Comment: Sorry, I just want to know why.Because I always be confusing about to include which file.So I want to know the reason in order to can remember it easily.Should be?

Comment: Read the manual page for the function you want to use, then add the `#include` statements that the manual page says you need. That way, you only need to remember the function names (the API), which should be a lot easier.

Comment: I known this.I just don't want to `man` everytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had found the answer from the wiki.

```
<sys/socket.h> Core BSD socket functions and data structures.

<netinet/in.h> AF INET and AF INET6 address families and their corresponding protocol families PF_INET and PF_INET6. Widely used on the Internet, these include IP addresses and TCP and UDP port numbers.

<sys/un.h> PF_UNIX/PF_LOCAL address family. Used for local communication between programs running on the same computer. Not used on networks.

<arpa/inet.h> Functions for manipulating numeric IP addresses.

<netdb.h> Functions for translating protocol names and host names into numeric addresses. Searches local data as well as DNS.
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets#Header_files